# Powershell [Add-Content/Write-Host] : Adding a hyperlink to plain text

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

**I have written a Powershell script to perform some actions:**

1. Read a .xls file
2. Compile certain .c files
3. Copy output files.

I log everything performed by the script to a Log file (e.g. `output.log`)

I later invoke a tool which performs an analysis of the actions performed by the script and writes them into an Excel sheet.

I would also like to write the path of the excel sheet inside `output.log` and also provide a hyperlink to it but I have not been able to do so.

**Example:**
Currently the link to the excel sheet is written as `file://\\10.128.163.188\d\abc.xls`, but I would like to have a hyperlink to it.

**Can you please suggest how to do that?**

p.s. I am not working with HTML Docs / UI (i found many examples for the same), but for adding a hyperlink into a plain text written inside a `.txt` file, i couldn't find any.

Comment: Huh? AFAIK you can't have a hyperlink in a plain text document. It won't be clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add hyperlinks to a `plaintext` document. It does not have that functionality.

It has to be a rich text file (`.rtf`), or a Microsoft Word Document (`.doc`), or a `HTML` file.
There is no way around this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Vasili Syrakis. Can you also let me know if its possible to add hyperlink if the filepath is written onto the console using Write-Host instead of a text file ?

Comment: That cannot be done inside the Powershell console either, although it can be done in `Bash` (unix shell)